# How to get the best indoor gps coordinates in objective c

Tags: ios, coordinates, cllocationmanager, latitude-longitude

How do I get the best Accuracy Indoor GPS Co-ordinates in device? Whenever I am launching the application in same location, the GPS value gets different different coordinates values. If, I will get the Proper coordinates, then only I can calculate the actual distance between the two coordinates and navigate a user.

**Here my sample code:**

```
_locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
_locationManager.delegate = self;
_locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
_locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLHeadingFilterNone; 
[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];


- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
  userLat = newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
  userLon = newLocation.coordinate.longitude;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

@batMan007 this is the best result you can get from the gps. You might be able to get a more accurate coordinate by connecting to a wifi network. Besides, if you are very particular about the distance in terms of meters, perhaps iBeacon is your only option.

Comment: for some reason we not using Ibeacon, from GPS We can't Absolute Coordinates ?